# Integrate Scrapy with Django : How to

Tags: python, django, scrapy

I'm still very new in Django
I am following [this](https://medium.com/@ali_oguzhan/how-to-use-scrapy-with-django-application-c16fabd0e62e) tutorial on how to integrate scrapy and django.

the problem is when i am trying to use my own spider it's just wont work.
I have tried the spider outside django and it's work just fine, some help will be very helpful.

This is my spider.py file

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

class NewsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
   name = 'detik'
   allowed_domains = ['news.detik.com']
   start_urls = ['https://news.detik.com/indeks/all/?date=02/28/2018']

def parse(self, response):  
    urls = response.xpath("//div/article/a/@href").extract()        
    for url in urls:
        url = response.urljoin(url)
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_detail)

    # follow pagination link
    page_next =   response.xpath("//a[@class = 'last']/@href").extract_first()
    if page_next:
        page_next = response.urljoin(page_next)
        yield scrapy.Request(url=page_next, callback=self.parse)

def parse_detail(self,response):
    x = {}
    x['breadcrumbs'] = response.xpath("//div[@class='breadcrumb']/a/text()").extract(),
    x['tanggal'] = response.xpath("//div[@class='date']/text()").extract_first(),
    x['penulis'] = response.xpath("//div[@class='author']/text()").extract_first(),
    x['judul'] = response.xpath("//h1/text()").extract_first(),
    x['berita'] = response.xpath("normalize-space(//div[@class='detail_text'])").extract_first(),
    x['tag'] = response.xpath("//div[@class='detail_tag']/a/text()").extract(),
    x['url'] = response.request.url,
    return x
```

this is my pipeline file

```
class DetikAppPipeline(object):

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    item = detikNewsItem()
    self.items.append(item['breadcrumbs'])
    self.items.append(item['tanggal'])
    self.items.append(item['penulis'])
    self.items.append(item['judul'])
    self.items.append(item['berita'])
    self.items.append(item['tag'])
    self.items.append(item['url'])
    item.save()
```

And this is the models file in django

```
class detikNewsItem(models.Model):
    breadcrumbs = models.TextField()
    tanggal = models.TextField()
    penulis = models.TextField()
    judul = models.TextField()
    berita = models.TextField()
    tag = models.TextField()
    url = models.TextField()

    @property
    def to_dict(self):
    data = {
        'url': json.loads(self.url),
        'tanggal': self.tanggal
    }
    return data

    def __str__(self):
        return self.url
```

Comment: “it's just wont work” is not very descriptive. Have you tried using debugging messages to find out at which point in the execution something unexpected happens? (e.g. some code is not reached)

Answer (score 5):

It's example how to write Scrapy pileline in Django project.

```
from <YOU_APP_NAME>.models import detikNewsItem

class DetikAppPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        d, created = detikNewsItem.objects.get_or_create(breadcrumbs=item['breadcrumbs'], url=item['url'])
        if created:        
            d.tanggal = item['tanggal']
            d.penulis = item['penulis']
            d.judul = item['judul']
            d.berita = item['berita']
            d.tag = item['tag']
            d.save()
        
        return item
```

By the way you need to run Scrapy in Django environment. There are several ways to do that:

1. Using `django-extensions` module.
   Need to create new file:

   `<DJANG_PROJECT>/scripts/__init__.py`
   `<DJANG_PROJECT>/scripts/run_scrapy.py`

With code inside:

```
from scrapy.cmdline import execute

execute(['run_scrapy.py', 'crawl', 'detik'])
```

2. Another way is to use Django Managment. Need to create folders in project with file:

   `<folder_of_app>/management/commands/__init__.py`
   `<folder_of_app>/management/commands/scrapy.py`
   `scrapy.py` file should contain code:

   ```
   from scrapy.cmdline import execute

   from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

   class Command(BaseCommand):
       help = 'Run scrapy.'

       def add_arguments(self, parser):
           parser.add_argument('arguments', nargs='+', type=str)

       def handle(self, *args, **options):
           args = []
           args.append('scrapy.py')
           args.extend(options['arguments'])
           execute(args)
   ```

It allow to run Scrapy in Django environment like this:

```
python manage.py scrapy crawl detik
python manage.py scrapy shell 'https://news.detik.com/indeks/all/?date=02/28/2018'
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but what i want to do is run scrapy from .html in django.it is still possible?
And i get this ScrapyItem matching query does not exist. but can't find what's wrong

Comment: Edit your post message using your fresh code. It allow to help you.

Comment: i actually realize the problem is in the pipelines. your code is unfortunely not working